# How to group a dataframe by date to get an array of ids for each group?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe:

```
id - title - publish_up - date

1  - Exampl- 2019-12-1  - datetime

...
```

I created a date column by applying

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publish_up'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

I am new in python and I am trying to learn pandas.
What I would like to do is to create groups for each day of the year.

The dataframe contains data from one year span, so in theory, there should be 365 groups.

Then, I would need to get an array of ids for each group.

example:

```
[{date:'2019-12-1',ids:[1,2,3,4,5,6]},{date:'2019-12-2',ids:[7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]},...]
```

Thank you

Comment: try to_dict() function of DataFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want format dates in strings in output list then convert to datetimes is not necessary, only create lists per groups by [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), convert it to `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last create list of dicts by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
print (df)
   id   title publish_up      date
0   1  Exampl  2019-12-2  datetime
1   2  Exampl  2019-12-2  datetime
2   2  Exampl  2019-12-1  datetime

#if necessary change format 2019-12-1 to 2019-12-01
#df['publish_up'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publish_up'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print (df.groupby('publish_up')['id'].agg(list).reset_index())
  publish_up      id
0  2019-12-1     [2]
1  2019-12-2  [1, 2]

a = df.groupby('publish_up')['id'].agg(list).reset_index().to_dict('r')
print (a)
[{'publish_up': '2019-12-1', 'id': [2]}, {'publish_up': '2019-12-2', 'id': [1, 2]}]
```